# phonegap camera crashes the app

Tags: cordova, nullpointerexception, camera, crash

Phonegap app crashes after several pictures taken using phonegap camera api.
It doesn't happen after each picture but only after several pictures taken.
I think RAM is not freed up which cause the crash. The message: Unfortunately Gallery has stopped.
Please, help, how to force free up RAM memory or other workaround.
What does it mean: W/QComExtractorFactory(174): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1

Thank you

Here is the LogCat:

11-27 18:06:55.751: E/camera(1799): Send tone bar: mSkinToneSeekBar = false

11-27 18:06:55.751: D/CameraStorage(1799): External storage state=mounted

11-27 18:06:55.771: E/WVMExtractor(174): Failed to open libwvm.so

11-27 18:06:55.771: W/QComExtractorFactory(174): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 5

11-27 18:06:55.771: W/QComExtractorFactory(174): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1

11-27 18:06:55.771: W/QComExtractorFactory(174): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1

11-27 18:06:55.771: W/QComExtractorFactory(174): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1

11-27 18:06:55.771: E/MM_OSAL(174): ValidateAACFile failed

11-27 18:06:55.771: W/QComExtractorFactory(174): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1 
11-27 18:06:55.771: W/QComExtractorFactory(174): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1

11-27 18:06:55.771: W/dalvikvm(1799): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41297438)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): java.lang.NullPointerException

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.camera.Camera.setDisplayOrientation(Camera.java:2232)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.camera.Camera.onConfigurationChanged(Camera.java:1992)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3673)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3805)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4875)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)

11-27 18:06:55.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

11-27 18:06:55.781: W/ActivityManager(634):   Force finishing activity com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.Camera

11-27 18:06:55.791: D/PowerManagerService(634): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=ActivityManager-Launch

11-27 18:06:55.791: W/ActivityManager(634):   Force finishing activity com.myapp.test/.test

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure that you are working like this.**

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURL){            
            fileURI = imageURL;
            fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileURI, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
                    fileSize = fileObj.size;
                    fileType = fileObj.type;                          
                });
            }); 
        }, function(){
             alert('failed');
        }, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        });
    },
```